# Clarification of an example on absolute convergence test of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

When testing whether or not series converge absolutely with a convergent $p$-series, we have to test it against $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|$.

In one of the text book examples, I'm having trouble understanding how that absolute value works. Any insight is appreciated!

The problem is as follows:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^ni^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

which converges absolutely by comparison with a convergent $p$-series with $p = 2$ because, for $n \ge 1$,

$\left\lvert\frac{(-1)^ni^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right\rvert = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \lt \frac {1}{n^2}$

I don't understand how the numerator is simplifying to just "1".

Comment: What is $|i|{}$?

Comment: Oh my goodness. Thank you. 1, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $i$ is the imaginary unit which in complex form is $ 0+1i$

In order to find the absolute value of $ a+bi$ we find $$\sqrt {a^2+b^2} $$

Thus $$ |i|= \sqrt 1 =1 $$

As a result we have $$ |(-1)^ni^{n+1}| =1$$